# Send Email with attachment by using URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to send an email with attachment.

I have no problem to send an email by using file path, but I prefer to set my attachment by using URL.

The email can sent successfully to my email without any attachment.

My PDF URL example: http://store/index.php/Store/GI/OrderID.pdf

Hope some can help me. Really Appreciate. Thank You.

Controller::

```
    public function SendInvoice(){
        $orderid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $result = $this->order->GetCustOrder($orderid);

        unset($data);
        $data = array(
                        $OrderID,
                        $result[0]->cust_id,
                        $result[0]->cust_name,
                        $result[0]->cust_email
                      );
        $this->store_email->SendInvoiceToCust($data); //library

        $this->session->set_flashdata('sent_email','Email has been sent to customer.');
        redirect('Store/Index');
    }
```

Library::

```
    public function SendInvoiceToCust($data){
        $message = "Dear Valued Customer, <br><br>Thank you for Purchased at Store. <br/><br/>Kindly refer the attachment to view your Invoice.";
        //$attached_file = base_url(). 'index.php/Store/GI/' .$data[0]. '.pdf';
        $form = base_url(). 'index.php/Store/GI/' .$data[0]. '.pdf';
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($form));

        $separator = md5(time());

        $message .= "--" . $separator . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"\" . $data[0]. '.pdf'\"" . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= $attachment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= "--" . $separator . "--";           

        $this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'Store');
        $this->email->to('email2@gmail.com'); 

        $this->email->subject('Store INVOICE [Do not reply]');
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach($attachment);
        $this->email->send();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet but you should try setting content type and encoding the pdf. 
The below is what I am currently using to send out an email with an attachement in codeigniter.
I have updated the response. This is currently how I am taking a pdf form and attaching it. 
Its all done within the $message field with different content transfer and types being set.

```
    $sender = "email@gmail.com";
    $emails = "email2@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Store INVOICE [Do not reply]";
    $headers = "From: " . $sender . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $message = "";

    $message = "--" . $separator . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= ($content = "Dear Valued Customer, <br><br>Thank you for Purchased at Store. <br/><br/>Kindly refer the attachment to view your Invoice.");
    $message .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

    $form = base_url(). 'index.php/Store/GI/' .$data[0]. '.pdf';
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($form));

    $separator = md5(time());

    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";

    $message .= "--" . $separator . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $data[0]. '.pdf'\"" . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= $attachment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    $result = mail($emails, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi, I had updated my code in the Library side and still can send email without attachment.

Comment: Kindly refer the attachment to view your Invoice.--be0bc20d2deda433249137aed2c1a216 Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="'1230'.pdf" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment aHR0cDovL3BnamV3ZWwucHVibGljZ29sZC5jb20ubXkvaW5kZXgucGhwL09yZGVyaW5nL0dlbmVy YXRlSW52b2ljZS8xMjMwLnBkZg== --be0bc20d2deda433249137aed2c1a216- [I got this in the email]

Comment: If you check out my updates above. As you dont need to re-attach the attachement as its included in the $message. Let me know how that goes.